# Windows 7 Fonts Folder Corrupted and Crashes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, fonts

I'm using Windows 7 (32-bit). Every time I open the Fonts folder, Windows Explorer crashes and restarts.

The Fonts folder has no icon:

[image: Fonts Folder has no icon]

If I open the Fonts folder:

[image: Windows Explorer is Restarting]

If I try to open "Change Font Settings" in Control panel, it's Blank:

[image: Font Settings is Blank]

The Install option doesn't appear in the context menu of any font, and if I open a font the Install button doesn't do anything.

What is causing this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: run **chkdsk C: /f** and **sfc /scannow**. if you still have issues, create a dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've already ran a chkdsk and sfc scan, unfortunately i can't upload the file because it's 92mb after compressing an i have too slow connection that i can't upload the file at least in 1day, so it there any other solution?

Comment: compress it as 7z (LZMA2, ULTRA) to get the best compression ratio. Do you have a friend/family members/public library who have a faster internet connection to upload the 7z file?

Comment: did you have a chance to upload the file?

Comment: Reviewers, please stop voting to close this question. It's a perfectly valid and clearly written question complete with images describing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Look in the Action Center for any issues. Go to Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Action Center or right-click the icon in the Notification Area (bottom right of screen). In the main window, click the drop-down arrow to the right of Maintenance where you can select View Reliability History. In View Reliability History, right-click on any Windows Explorer errors and View technical details, which may be of help.

   Also, at the bottom, click View All Problem reports and Check for Solutions.
2. If (1) above doesn’t help, the problem is sometimes caused by a third-party extension. ShellExView can be useful to see which shell extensions have been introduced into Explorer. Read about it then scroll down near to the bottom to download the x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) (It looks pretty shady, but don't worry, it's safe)[.

   When you run it, click on the column labelled Company to alphabetically sequence the entries. You have to assume that the Microsoft entries are bona fide, so concentrate on the third-party entries. Is there anything listed that is either unnecessary or unknown? If so, highlight it and click the red spot (top left) to disable it. There shouldn’t be too many of them but you may find it easier to disable them all, then re-enable them (green spot) one at a time and try Explorer until the culprit is found.